# How to find the origin of a file

Tags: windows

Is it possible to determine where a picture file came from? Whether it was downloaded/saved from the Internet or if it came from an external source like a camera or phone ?

Comment: Exif data might help if its straight off a camera, but that's trivial to remove.

Comment: Google Reverse Image Search https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?hl=en may find the image if it is currently on the internet. Unfortunately that won't tell you if was uploaded from a camera or phone.

Answer (score 0):

If a photo is on the Internet, it originated from a camera (or other imaging device), so it came from a camera either way.  Some cameras save identifying metadata with the picture and some don't.  If the camera saved it, it may or may not be removed if the image is stored on a web site.  So the presence or absence of metadata doesn't tell you whether the image was on the Internet before it got to you.  If there is metadata, it might contain information related to the source.  You can use a service like Tin Eye to see if the picture can be found in public areas of the Internet, but if it is, it could mean only that the originator shared it publicly as well as with you.  However, information from Tin Eye or another image search engine could shed light on the source of the online picture.